# How do I send logs to syslog in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, syslog

Syslog is a client/server protocol: a logging application transmits a text message to the syslog receiver.

I need to log to this syslog server.  How would I do it using classic ASP?

Comment: classic ASP runs on the server, so you want to send a message from one server to another server ?

Comment: @Dee, that is the point. Syslog collects (error) data from different (other) servers into a single place where you can store, filter or monitor these messages.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Syslog COM component to write syslog messages from classic ASP.
Besides providing classic ASP with a generic industry-standard logging solution, it can also come in handy when you're running a Windows Docker container running a Classic ASP application.
IIS under Docker doesn't write a default log to stdout/console. Using Syslog you can still log from IIS inside a Windows Docker container.

The ActiveX syslog component can be found at https://gitlab.com/erik4/syslog-com-client.